# Forked project return unauthorized token

Tags: reactjs, api, unauthorized

So I have just completed my coding boot camp and wanted my final React project on my github to show potential employers. I forked my final project from my school's github. Everything was running smoothly prior to when i forked the project, but i wanted to ensure it would load in case other employers want to check it out. I did a git clone to my personal repo and installed all my files including my env files. I did a yarn start only to get this :

```
invalid request error message -  **{"type":"https://httpstatus.es/401",
    "status":401, "title":"Unauthorized",
    "detail":"Access token invalid or expired"}**
```

My api and secret keys are still active and my api file from petfinder-sdk i pulled from github to my project handles the token key generation.

link to my repo - https://github.com/mrshawnhum/capstone-starter-mrshawnhum

Comment: It looks like you're having trouble with the getAllPets third-party API call. Not sure if it's a free API, would you be able to generate another key/secret pair?

Comment: I am sure i can if i contact their customer service, but would rather keep that option on my back pocket

Comment: this is hardly an issue with git, is it ? updated the tags accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how an access token could expire, going to the pointed url points to a very public page [describing the "401" error](https://httpstatuses.com/401).

If the dependency comes from your code : rewrite your code so that it doesn't make an http request to the web just for fetching a description of an HTTP status. Or at least, doesn't try to authenticate, if the public information is OK.

If the dependency comes from a module : track the culprit, see if you can easily change its behavior (make an unautenticated call ? a config variable at setup ? dropping this module in favor of another one ? ...).